# Overlapping intervals and the amount of overlaps

Tags: php, algorithm, intervals, overlap

This question might be similar to others but is a bit different. Let's say we have a set of intervals that goes like this let's say A-9 are numbers but for the sake of formatting I used letters):

```
            <-a---> <------c--->
        <------------MAIN>
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
         <--d-> <--b------->
```

So we have the Main interval which goes from `I` to `Z`, the interval `a` that goes from `M` to `S`  and so on.

Now I want to have the intervals where I have the most overlaps WITHIN the main one (which is essentially the basic constraint) that would be M-O with (a and d) and Q-S (a and b) and U-Z (b and c) with 2 overlaps each (everything beyond `Z` is out of the question because it is outside the main interval

I essentially want a list (aka array) of the intervals and the number of overlaps inside the Main, while not counting the main into that number (sorting not needed there are enough ways to do this) in PHP.

I thought of making a picture of the intervals and then counting the colors for each pixel column but that's

1. averting the problem
2. inefficient
3. probably pretty slow

so, TLDR, I need a solution that

- works in PHP
- is *relatively* fast
- is reliable
- gives you the overlapping intervals with their overlap count
- has a main interval used as base constraint which is not counted to the overlap.

I know it's a very specific question but I am not that well versed in Math and algorithms.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your corrections but I had a question getting -5 (no one of the downvoters said anything) and closed as unclear what I ask even though I tried to follow most thing including a TLDR and the question was not exactly a duplicate because of the no-javascript requirement and some other small stuff which made it relatively unique

Comment: I agree that downvotes without comments are not very helpful, but voting commentary still does not belong in posts (and stating that a post is not off-topic does not make it on-topic). If you want to add meta-remarks, you can always do it in the comments (I don't know if it makes much difference to voting anyway).

Answer (score 1):

- Build 2 vectors. One contains the start points and one contains the end points of each interval.
- Sort the 2 vectors.
- While you have something in any of the two vectors:

  - pick the minimum between the 2.
  - If you picked it from the vector with start points increment the number of overlapping intervals by 1, else decrease it by 1.
  - If your point is also the starting point of the main interval set a flag that you results are valid now.
  - If your point is the end point of the main interval you can stop.
  - If the flag is set then you can compare the current number of overlapping intervals with the max so far and update accordingly.

You can decrease 1 from the max to ignore the main interval. You can keep a list of sections where you have the max count (Just make sure you clear it when you getter a better result).

This is O(NlogN) with the number of intervals you have.

Comment: this sounds complicated...

what do you exactly mean with a vector (in relation to PHP I didnt find that much) should I make a vactor graphic or what?

also sort by what? by their plain starting/ending point, so I had one that would by JMQU and OS15 for the start and end points or sort by the start points and set the end points in relation to that?

Comment: vector/array/list whatever you want that can hold multiple things inside PHP arrays would do.
One should contain the starting points and the other the end points. I assume you have something like numbers for each of them (dates or indexes work just as well, anything as long as you can sort). You should sort them independently for the algorithm to work.

Comment: okay NOW I get it, I thought it could be along that lines but since I wasnt really sure I wanted to ask.
so in the end I get two arrays like in my comment above (plus the points from main)

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm for this is go over the whole length with a counter that increases when you meet a start point and decreases when you meet an end point.

Keep track of the maximum this counter gets to.

Go over the whole length again, this time add locations to your `result` array when:
1. You are within the MAIN part borders.
2. Your counter (which is maintained the same way) is equal to the maximum you calculated before.

Comment: well it isnt just the maximum but for lower values I essentially have to go over this again over and over? but sounds techinically legit

Comment: @My1 - at every point you have the value of the counter and can decide what to do with it. What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I want to have the overlaps and the overlap count of more or less all overlaps in an array (I can sort by count later)