# comparing four date sets and calculate the overlaying hours in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime, difference

I'm having a (small) issue regarding a time calculator in PHP.
The problem is the following:

I have four dates (all on the same day) but different hours.
There is a group A and a group B which is like:

GROUP A:

```
from 9:00 till 12:00
```

GROUP B:

```
from 10:30 till 12:30
```

What I need is a way to check if group b falls in group a (which it does for 2 hours), and if it falls in group a then it has to calculate for how many hours it does. After that it has to add the remaining hours that were not overlapsing `(which is 12:00 till 12:30 so 30 minutes)`.

So the answer of this calculation should be `2.5 hours`, because `group B` was in `group A` for `2 hours` and then it had a half hour `(0.5) out of group A`.

I hope that someone can help me with this because I have no idea how to calculate this in PHP.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989461/overlapping-intervals-and-the-amount-of-overlaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be 2, because group B was in group A for 1.5 hours not 2 hours:

```
$time1_1 = '01-02-2016 9:00';
$time1_2 = '01-02-2016 12:00';
$time2_1 = '01-02-2016 10:30';
$time2_2 = '01-02-2016 12:30';

$hourdiff1 = round((strtotime($time1_2) - strtotime($time2_1))/3600, 1);
$hourdiff2 = round((strtotime($time2_2) - strtotime($time1_2))/3600, 1);

$hourdiff = $hourdiff1 + $hourdiff2;
echo $hourdiff;
```

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763476/how-do-i-find-the-hour-difference-between-two-dates-in-php) is reference.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great and I understand the code/logic behind a system like this better now!